# performSegueWithIdentifier says has no identifier for segue. But I did set it. What's wrong?

Tags: ios, xcode

The title says it all. I am trying to call this method on the click of a button but once I click it my application crashes with that error code: no identifier for segue - but I did set it! What might be wrong?

Comment: Show us a screenshot of the identifier on the segue you're calling, and the statement from the controller where you're calling `self performsegue`. I'm telling you, there is a mismatch ;)

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/IZaGR

Comment: Alright you got it wrong indeed :) let me type a detailed answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A segue is a storyboard link between two `UIViewControllers`, you add them by dragging between two controllers using right clic or ctrl + clic.

They look like this [image: segue]

It's the little arrow in the middle.

Clic on it, and go in the Attributes inspector (the little icon on the top right that looks like a shield).

There, you can set the segue identifier.

It looks like this [image: segue]

Note this is an old screenshot that I randomly took by a quick search, but it still looks very much like this.

You have to  call **that** identifier in code, **NOT** the storyboard ID of the controller. They are two very different things, even though it's easy to think otherwise at first.

The reason you are calling the segue from code, and not the controller, is (among other things) because you can set various settings in the segue, like the animation style, or if there is an animation at all.

You can look at many guides online to see what you can do with segues (and unwind segues !). But at first, the default settings will do just fine for learning.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, however my problem still persists because I can't to set these fields (grey colored text). Why is that the case?

Comment: the "Identifier" field is greyed out, is that what you're saying? Are you 100% certain you're in the segue settings, in the correct panel?

Comment: I don't want to sound like an arrogant person but if you're about to say yes, please provide a large screenshot of your screen :P

Comment: Well that's it, you should be able to type in that "Identifier" field ; the grey "Identifier" is only there as a placeholder. left clic in there and type "MapDetails" and it'll work just fine (unless your segue is on the wrong controllers, which i doubt)

Comment: There you go :) Don't be afraid of trial and error before asking around ; also, googling the error should've lead you on the right path without needing to ask. But i was happy to help nonetheless !